# Is it possible to extract source code from an MDL file?

Tags: vba, microstation

I need to extract source code (probably written in VB) from a microstation MDL file.
Is it possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look [here](https://communities.bentley.com/products/programming/microstation_programming/f/microstation-programming---forum/123282/need-to-modify-a-ma-file) they state:

> You can't edit a `.ma` file.  A `.ma` is usually an MDL application.  To rebuild an MDL application you must have the source code (usually in a `.mc` or `.cpp` file).  If you don't have the source code, you can't rebuild the application.

I am afraid the answer is no, it is not possible.